# Function in R to Sum up Individual Multiplications Over Same Cell Contents

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I was having a difficult time in R to get a code running over my time series, as I am diving deeper into this programming language.

In a dataset I want to multiply the sales on a specific day of a product with the price of these sales and sum the individual multiplications up to get the total sales volume for every product over the time series.

| product_code | sales_per_day | price_per_unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| product_1 | 1 | 23,4 |
| product_1 | 6 | 22,1 |
| product_1 | 0 | 0 |
| ... |  |  |
| product_2 | 46 | 6,0 |
| ... |  |  |
| product_999 | 2 | 12,32 |

and the final dataset should be somewhere around here:

| product_code | summed_up_total_sales |
| --- | --- |
| product_1 | 47838,32 |
| product_2 | 7810,12 |
| product_3 | 45278,91 |
| product_4 | 719273,88 |
| product_5 | 50183,77 |
| ... | ... |
| product_999 | 6281,39 |

I found out about the `crossproduct` function in r that takes two matrixes and multiplies every cell of the first matrix with the corresponding cell in the second matrix.

My initial guess was to sum up the `sales_per_day` and multiply them with the summed up `price_per_unit`. However, the complexity lies in the varying prices per unit that would then be neglected.

Now my guess would be to use a loop that goes through every cell, multiplies the `sales_per_day` with the price based on the `product_code` and finally sums them up based on the `product_code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work :

```
df2 = df %>% 
group_by(day, product_code) %>%
summarise(amount_per_product = sales_per_day*price_per_unit) %>%
ungroup() %>%
group_by(day) %>%
summarise(total_per_day = sum(amount_per_product)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, the grou_by() function seems to be the right way. However, I get this error-message                                                                                                       
--- 'Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `amount_per_product`.
i `amount_per_product = sales_per_day* price_per_unit`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i The error occurred in group 1: date = 2020-01-01, product_code = "product_10".'   ---                  I changed the "day" to "date" since the dataframe is ordered by the date format you see in the error message

Comment: There seems to be a problem with something that should be numeric is not numeric. product_10 interestingly is the following product after the first product_1. Maybe there is a problem with the date-format? Since the recording of almost every product starts on the 01-01-2020. Any ideas? Oh, and the cells where there are no sales, therefore no prices, I set to 0 in the dataset. They were empty initially in the csv

Comment: most likely the `typeof(df$price_ per_unit)` is non numeric . Try something like `gsub(",",".",df$price_per_unit)` to change the comma to a dot and then try `as.numeric(df$price_per_unit)` to convert it to number format.

Comment: I had to manually change a few things in dataset. Namely the , to . and fill up blanks with 0's. In the second group_by i chose product_code instead. Thanks a lot thehand0, it works now!